# Showing time as Eastern Time in Velocity template

Tags: java, velocity

My Server time is in UTC.

However, I need to show the time as Eastern time. In jsp (jstl), I am using the code:

```
<fmt:formatDate pattern="MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss"
                        value="${user.startDate}" timeZone="America/New_York"/>
```

Need to show same in my emails which use velocity templates. How can the same be achieved in velocity template?

Can I parameterize `$dateTool.format()` to include time zone?

Comment: Isn't that what [the standard implementation already allows](https://velocity.apache.org/tools/2.0/apidocs/org/apache/velocity/tools/generic/DateTool.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.util.Locale,%20java.util.TimeZone))?

Comment: what would be the "Locale" for New York?

Comment: Last time I was there NY sat on the east coast of the US, so I'd try [Locale.US](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#US)